# How to make conditional logic form using AngularJS only?

Tags: angularjs, html, dom, conditional-statements

I have tried using HTML-DOM...but the problem is that they don't seem to be working with radio buttons.
Is there somthing which would help me in this using purely angular?
I have tried many methods but the problem with radio button continues.
please help me find a solution soon..

```html
Toy material:
<input type="radio" name="Ttyp" ng-model="1" value="plastic" required>plastic
<input type="radio" name="Ttyp" ng-model="2" value="wood" required>wood<br><br>


<div ng-show="2">
  toy name: <input type="radio" name="Tname" ng-required="2" value="Our Venue">Our Venue
  <input type="radio" name="Tname" ng-required="2" value="Your Venue">Your Venue
</div>
<br><br>
```

**edit**
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch {may be this could help}

Comment: try this: <div *ngIf="2">

Comment: Can you expand your answer please? As in edit the code mentoined in the Q?

Comment: Read tbe documentation -- [AngularJS input type=radio Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D).

Comment: @georgeawg i don't want to display the selected option name....